# how to use json input on Top Hit aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I ' ve tried this on **Max aggreagation** and it works.

```
{ "script": "doc['my_number_value'].value * 10"     }
```

But when I tried it on my **Top Hit Aggreagation** it does not work.

it gives

> internal error

How can use **json input** for Top Hit Aggregation.

for more details: look image

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: A complete one (with the full aggregation part), so we could reproduice it on our side.

Comment: thanks for answer, a complete part is : { "script": "doc['my_number_value'].value * 10"     }

Comment: @LeBigCat I add a picture